# Empty Cart button in Mini Cart. woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

Is it possible to add an **empty cart button** inside a mini cart? I managed to do that on a cart page but having issue with a mini cart.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_buttons', 'add_clear_cart_button', 20 );
function add_clear_cart_button() {
    echo "<a class='button' href='?empty-cart=true'>" . __( 'Empty Cart', 'woocommerce' ) . "</a>";
}
```

Am I using a wrong action?

Comment: You should specify what issue are you having so that others can help you. Also please specify if the code you've provided is the one you use in both cases or in one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add below function in function.php for empty cart button

```
<?php
// check for empty-cart get param to clear the cart
add_action( 'init', 'woocommerce_clear_cart_url' );
function woocommerce_clear_cart_url() {
  global $woocommerce;

    if ( isset( $_GET['empty-cart'] ) ) {
        $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart(); 
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_buttons', 'add_clear_cart_button', 10, 2 );
function add_clear_cart_button() {
    ?>
    <a class="button" href="<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>?empty-cart"><?php _e( 'Empty Cart', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
    <?php
} 
?>
```

Comment: @ShitalMarakana I have put this code in `funcation.php` but not working from my end.
Any other solution?

Comment: @ShitalMarakana I've also put this code in funcation.php and It didn't work. Any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here are you latest update together with Cart's "Empty Cart" button:

```
// Check for empty-cart get param to clear the cart
add_action('init', 'woocommerce_clear_cart_url');
function woocommerce_clear_cart_url() {
    if (isset($_GET['empty-cart'])) {
        WC()->cart->empty_cart();
    }
}

// Add "Empty Cart" button to the main cart page
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_coupon', 'add_clear_cart_button' );
function add_clear_cart_button() {
    ?>
    <a class="button" href="<?php echo esc_url(WC()->cart->get_cart_url() . '?empty-cart'); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Empty Cart', 'woocommerce'); ?></a>
    <?php
}

// Add "Empty Cart" button to the mini cart
add_action('woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_buttons', 'add_mini_cart_empty_button');
function add_mini_cart_empty_button() {
    ?>
    <a class="button" href="<?php echo esc_url(wc_get_cart_url() . '?empty-cart'); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Empty Cart', 'woocommerce'); ?></a>
    <?php
}
```